# Validity of Gauss Markov Theorem under specific cases

Tags: regression, self-study, least-squares

This is part of an homework, so even just the intuition of proof would be appreciated.

Having a linear model $ Y_i=\beta'X+\varepsilon_i$ I have a number of cases under which I need to determine if the Gauss Markov theorem is still valid. The three cases I'm stuck with are

a) $ E(Y_i-\mu_i|X_i)^2=X_i^2   \ \ \ \  with \ \ \mu_i=E(Y_i|X_i)$.

My reasoning is that $ E(Y_i-\mu_i|X_i)^2=E(\varepsilon_i)^2=X_i^2$ and being $ X_i$ a deterministic observed variable there should no problems with such a result but this solution seems too weak.

b) $X_i=(1,X_{1i},X_{2i},X_{1i}X_{2i})$
This one is the one I'm completely stuck with. I started by looking at Gauss Markov assumptions, but the model can be represented as a linear one

$ 
\beta_0+\beta_1X_{1i}+\beta_2X_{2i}+\beta_2X_{1i}X_{2i}+\varepsilon_i
$

And his variance should be equal to the variance of $ \varepsilon_i$ with no reason to believe that it violate heteroskedasticity. With this one I'm really not sure about what I should try to prove the GM theorem

c) $ X_1=(1,X_{1i},X_{2i},(X_{1i}-X_{2i})) $

For this point I tried representing the model in an "complete" way

$ Y_i= \beta_0+\beta_{1i}X_{1i}+\beta_{21}X_{21}+\beta_{3i}(X_{1i}-X_{2i}) + \varepsilon_i $ but by multiplying the last elements and collecting we can see that

$ Y_i=\beta_0+(\beta_{1i}+\beta_{3i})X_{1i}+(\beta_{2i}-\beta_{3i})X_{2i} + \varepsilon_i=\beta_0+\gamma_{1i}X_{1i}+\gamma_{2i}X_{2i}+\varepsilon_{i}$

This means that reducing the number of variables we get an alternative model with less parameters estimations and therefore less variability. This means that the OLS estimator based on the original model is not the best one.

I'm not sure about the conclusion of this one either

Edit: adding attempts.

Comment: Please [read about our policy](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and tell us more what have you tried and where are you stuck?

Comment: Question: Ad 1) What is $\mu_i$ supposed to represent? Ad 2) Is this supposed to be compared with another model? I.e. a model without an interaction? Ad 3) Notice that $X_{1i} - X_{2i}$ is a linear combination of $X_{1i}$ and $X_{2i}$ - here you are on the right path!

Comment: $ \mu_i $ is supposed to represent the conditional mean (added in the question). No it should not be compared with another model, I should only state if Gauss Markov Theorem applies in these a model with there cases